# TYPO3 6.2 Error '$hookObject must implement interface' at backend

Tags: php, typo3, updates, backend, typo3-6.2.x

I've made an extension update at my TYPO3 6.2.19-Website, but the update failed, so I step back to the previous version of the extension `fluidcontent`.

Now my Homepage is a blank, white Page, but all other subpages are still there. At the backend, I've get this error after login:

```
$hookObject must implement interface TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface
```

`TYPO3 6.2.19`, `PHP 5.6.20`, `Configuration presets Development`, ...

How can I recover my Website? What 'tells me' the error message at backend?

[image: error typo3 backend hookPbject]

[image: error typo3 backend panel]

Comment: I also tried to downgrade the typo3-core version, but I've got still the same error `/typo3_src-6.2.17/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/View/PageLayoutView.php in line 1471.`

Comment: have you installed the bootstrap extension?

Comment: no, I use `fluidcontent`with `flux`. I think the problem must be with `fluidcontent`because that's the ext. I've tried to update. No bootstrap ext. or sth. else

Comment: could you post me the ext_localconf.php of fluidcontent?

Comment: I insert the ext_localconf.php at my post ..

Comment: seems to be ok, you can remove it from your post again if you want to... so i can't find an error there but i am 99% sure it has something to do with an old/not updated extension. It's hard to say without seeing more of your system, but it`s too much/impossible to post everything on here.

Comment: My homepage is visible if I had an normal text content on it, but If I insert a new fluid content .. the page is white.  There must be an error with `fluidcontent`but I took the version back to `4.4.3`...

Answer (score 1):

the problem has sth. to do with `fluidcontent`, because every page (uid) with fluid content elements was false. So I've got the latest `fluidcontent` who supported `TYPO3 6.2`- it's `4.3.3`. Nothing happend at all ... I've got still the error message (s. initial post)

After a long time .. I also change the `flux` to `7.3.2`and that was it. I've made a mistake to update the ext. `fluidcontent`an `flux`, but the latest versions do not support `TYPO3 6.2`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case downgrade `flux` - solved this problem. Look `flux` compatible with TYPO3 6.x or 7.x and use just 6.x compatible